# GBQ Transpose Table in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose, unpivot

Trying to transpose a table in GBQ. The solution needs to be able to work dynamically with varying columns and rows. I know there is a way to do this by listing out columns specifically, but I have varying tables with large numbers of rows. There is an unpivot function in GBQ now and my idea was to Unpivot, then Pivot it. Not sure if anyone has dealt with this yet?

Starting Data

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * from data
  unpivot (value for Fruit in (Apple, Bananas, Orange))
)
pivot (max(value) for `Group` in ('North', 'South', 'West'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Below version builds all references needed for unpivot and pivot dynamically on fly

```
execute immediate (select '''select * from (
  select * from `project.dataset.table`
  unpivot (value for Fruit in (''' || (select array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":'), ', ')
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1) || ''')) 
)
pivot (max(value) for `Group` in (''' || (select '"' || string_agg(distinct `Group`, '", "' order by `Group`) || '"' from `project.dataset.table`) || '''))
'''
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mikhail. I understand how to do it this way, I am looking for a way to do it dynamically  where columns and row values can change overtime. I have tried to create variables and do  
unpivot (value for Fruit in (Select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) but this gives an error

Comment: I see, no problem. will update answer shortly :o)

Comment: Thamk Mikhail, I am running into an issue in my code where for the subsequent columns of North, South and West are not all numeric data type. Some are int. Is there a way to mass convert these to numeric? Other than Casting each on individually?