# Turning Columns into Rows at Big Query

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

Need some help running a Query in Big Query from Google Sheets.

How the data is (at GoogleSheets):

```
_____|_____| Product1 | Product2 | Product3| ...
     |Spec1|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
G1   |Spec2|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
_____|Spec3|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
     |Spec4|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
G2   |Spec5|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
_____|Spec6|  Value   |  Value   |  Value  | ...
.
.
.
```

where G1, G2 [...] are a group of spec's (not really useful for the query I want).
where Spec1, Spec2 [...] are characteristics of the products.
where Value's are the qualification of each spec.

How I'd like it to be at the query:

```
Product | Spec 1 | Spec 2 | Spec 3 | Spec 4 | Spec 5 | Spec 6 | ...
Product1|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
Product2|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
Product3|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
Product4|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
Product5|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
Product6|  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value |  Value | ...
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to do that?
Seems like an newbie question because it really is. (LOL) Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Formula for you**

```
=TRANSPOSE({data range})
```

**Example**

[image]

**Function References**

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

Comment: I actually know the transpose formula for Google Sheets. The thing is: I can't modify the Google Sheets source file and I want to make a query available for everyone at the office to use.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table
  unpivot (Value for Product in (Product1, Product2, Product3))
)
pivot (any_value(Value) for Spec in ('Spec1','Spec2','Spec3','Spec4','Spec5','Spec6'))
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a good workaround. One question though: is there a way in which I don't need to specify Product and Specs? The number of Products and Specs are dynamic, therefore I'm not always limited to 3 products or 6 specs only.

i.e: in "unpivot (Value for Product in First Row))" instead of naming each Product.
Same for Specs.

p.s.: I'm not sure what I'm saying exists. I'm new to BigQuery (and SQL).

Comment: see [GBQ Transpose Table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68202808/gbq-transpose-table-in-sql)